# Extract certificate from SSLContext

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm creating SSLContext in standard way:

- take .p12 certificate file,
- create KeyStore and load certificate into it,
- create KeyManagerFactory, init it with KeyStore, and get KeyManagers,
- create TrustManagerFactory, init it with null, and get TrustManagers.
- create SSLContext and init it with KeyManagers and TrustManagers.

The question is - how can I extract KeyStore and certificate data back from SSLContext? The task is to obtain fingerprint hash from certficate.

Is it even possible or I have to get it separately, reading certificate from file?

Comment: If you have KeyStore then you can get certificate like this `Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);`, but you have to know alias (name) of this certificate before you use that. And then Get Fingerprint is also easy `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(cert.getFingerprint());`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done if you have a custom TrustManager. You can refer to this [link](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs56/examples/ldap/SimpleQuery/InstallCert.java) for that custom class. Look for the private `SavingTrustManager` static class.

And the place where you are using the java's default TrustManager, use this class so that you can retrieve the certificate that the server sent.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(dummyTrustStore);

X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];

SavingTrustManager savingTrustManager = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { savingTrustManager }, null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
```

**And after you have started the handshake**, you can get the certificates from the SavingTrustManager from the static member variable `chain`, like:

> savingTrustManager.chain

Comment: So to get certificate info I've to make a connection? Well, not what I intended to do, but thanks anyway.